# WPF dynamic menuItem creation error

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a file menu, where on load, some `menuItems` are populated from filenames in a directory.

```
<MenuItem 
    x:Name="LayoutLoad" 
    Header="Load saved layout" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Width="200"
    />
```

//on load (code behind)

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("Settings/layouts");
for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Count(); i++)
{
    MenuItem item = new MenuItem {
        Header = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePaths[i]),
        Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePaths[i])
    };
    item.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Chooselayout);
    LayoutLoad.Items.Add(item);
}
```

This was working great, until a moment ago, and now it will not compile, crashing on:

```
MenuItem item = new MenuItem {
            Header = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePaths[i]),
            Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePaths[i])
        };
```

with:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: The invocation of the constructor on type 'Form_beta.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.
```

If I comment out that code and replace it with:

`string test = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePaths[i]);`

It works fine, and returns the filepath I would expect.

What has gone wrong here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It probably just means that it threw an exception and then you didn't call Initialize() in the ctor.  Maybe because it returned null on GetFiles()?

Try turning on Exceptions for CLI under Windows->Exceptions and tick that box.  Then it should break on the exceptions.

Comment: Ah, thank you. There was a file in the directory with a space in the name, which could not be used as a Header for the menuItem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. the exception was caused by a file in the directory with a space in the name, which could not be used as a Header for the menuItem.